# Filter elements and change URL with JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, filter

I need help with JavaScript/jQuery solution, how to make filter for products with URL changing.

- when click on checkbox then show checked colors
- when checked more filters show all colors which are checked
- if click on "Show all", show all colors (uncheck all filters)
- clicking on filter will change URL:
  red = #f/red;
  blue = #f/blue;
  red and blue together = #f/red/blue
- when page is opened, check url and apply filters

Thank you for help Tomas

https://jsfiddle.net/tundyh1g/1/

```css
    .filterelements {
      display: block;
      width: 210px;
    }

    .red,
    .green,
    .blue,
    .redgreen,
    .redblue {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      float: left;
      margin: 10px;
    }

    .red {
      background: #ff2600;
    }

    .green {
      background: #a5de00;
    }

    .blue {
      background: #0087ff;
    }

    .redgreen {
      background: rgb(255, 38, 0);
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 38, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(165, 222, 0, 1) 100%);
    }

    .redblue {
      background: rgb(255, 38, 0);
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 38, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 135, 255, 1) 100%);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" name="all">Show all</button>
  <input type="checkbox" name="red" value="red">red
  <input type="checkbox" name="blue" value="blue">green
  <input type="checkbox" name="green" value="green">blue



  <hr />
  <div class="filterelements">
    <div class="red" rel="color:red"></div>
    <div class="green" rel="color:green"></div>
    <div class="blue" rel="color:blue"></div>
    <div class="redgreen" rel="color:red|color:green"></div>
    <div class="green" rel="color:green"></div>
    <div class="red" rel="color:red"></div>
    <div class="redblue" rel="color:red|color:blue"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
$('.selector button').click(function() {
  $('.selector input').prop("checked",true).trigger("change");
});

$('.selector input').change(function() {
  $('.filterelements div').hide();
  $('.selector input:checked').each(function() {
      $('.filterelements div.' + $(this).val()).show();
  })
});
```

*Note*

I've wrapped your `button` and `input` inside a div with the class `selector`, Also
I've separated classes like `class="redblue"` into `class="red blue"`

**Demo**

```js
$('.selector button').click(function() {
  $('.selector input').prop("checked", true).trigger("change");
});

$('.selector input').change(function() {
  $('.filterelements div').hide();
  $('.selector input:checked').each(function() {
    $('.filterelements div.' + $(this).val()).show();
  })

  if ($('.selector input:checked').length == 0) {
    $('.filterelements div').show();
  }
});
```

```css
.filterelements {
  display: block;
  width: 210px;
}

.red,
.green,
.blue,
.redgreen,
.redblue {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

.red {
  background: #ff2600;
}

.green {
  background: #a5de00;
}

.blue {
  background: #0087ff;
}

.redgreen {
  background: rgb(255, 38, 0);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 38, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(165, 222, 0, 1) 100%);
}

.redblue {
  background: rgb(255, 38, 0);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 38, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 135, 255, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="selector">
    <button type="button" name="all">Show all</button>
    <input type="checkbox" name="red" value="red">red
    <input type="checkbox" name="blue" value="blue">green
    <input type="checkbox" name="green" value="green">blue
  </div>



  <hr />
  <div class="filterelements">
    <div class="red" rel="color:red"></div>
    <div class="green" rel="color:green"></div>
    <div class="blue" rel="color:blue"></div>
    <div class="red green" rel="color:red|color:green"></div>
    <div class="green" rel="color:green"></div>
    <div class="red" rel="color:red"></div>
    <div class="red blue" rel="color:red|color:blue"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for quick answer. I have got two questions: 
Is it possible show all, when nothing is checked? - when click all, then uncheck all checkboxes and show all content

How to change and read it from URL?

Comment: @TomášSiničák I've updated the demo with the solution for when you uncheck all. about the Url, that is a separate question, so you have to make a new question regarding that.

Comment: Thanks for support, I have got last question: Is it possible to change so that the filter has to meet all the conditions? E.g. if I select the checkbox green and red, then only the element that has both classes will be displayed.

Comment: @Andersen Have you got any idea please?

Comment: @TomášSiničák Yes but like your URL question then you move away from what this question was about. Problem is that if I change the answer to something that don't match your original question then it might confuse others.

Answer (score 0):

First, on button click checked all checkbox using `.prop("checked", true)` and then on change on of checkbox check of checkbox checked length is more than 0 then hide all and display only those who is checked else show all.

```js
$('button[name="all"]').click(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked",true).trigger("change");
});

$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change',function(){
  $('.filterelements div').hide();
  if( $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0 ){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
        $('.'+$(this).val()).show();
    });
  }else{
    $('.filterelements div').show();
  }
})
```

```css
.filterelements {
      display: block;
      width: 210px;
    }

    .red,
    .green,
    .blue,
    .redgreen,
    .redblue {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      float: left;
      margin: 10px;
    }

    .red {
      background: #ff2600;
    }

    .green {
      background: #a5de00;
    }

    .blue {
      background: #0087ff;
    }

    .redgreen {
      background: rgb(255, 38, 0);
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 38, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(165, 222, 0, 1) 100%);
    }

    .redblue {
      background: rgb(255, 38, 0);
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 38, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 135, 255, 1) 100%);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" name="all">Show all</button>
  <input type="checkbox" name="red" value="red">red
  <input type="checkbox" name="green" value="green">green
  <input type="checkbox" name="blue" value="blue">blue



  <hr />
  <div class="filterelements">
    <div class="red" rel="color:red"></div>
    <div class="green" rel="color:green"></div>
    <div class="blue" rel="color:blue"></div>
    <div class="redgreen" rel="color:red|color:green"></div>
    <div class="green" rel="color:green"></div>
    <div class="red" rel="color:red"></div>
    <div class="redblue" rel="color:red|color:blue"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I choose @CarstenLøvboAndersen solution. I don't now why someon downvote your answer.

Comment: I give the solution first what for what you asked. "Is it possible show all, when nothing is checked? - when click all, then uncheck all checkboxes"

Comment: Sorry I don't know where is problem... In your solution, when I click all, all checkboxes are checked.